# F# applying function to it's result n-times

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am trying to find a functional correct way for the following piece of code:

```
let mutable u = initialize cities pms
for i in 0 .. 10 do
    u <- randomIteration u pms distances
```

randomIteration is a simple function which takes an array with 2 more parameters and returns a modified array. This process has to be repeated n-times (10 here).

I came up with a solution, which uses fold, but I am creating a "dummy" sequence just to be able to fold on it, which does not seem right.

```
let result = Seq.init 10 (fun i -> i) |> Seq.fold (fun uNext i -> randomIteration uNext pms distances) u
```

I could also use recursion with a counter variable, but that as well seems ackward. Am I just missing a simple right solution?

Comment: Answers given are good, just wanted to point out that this is exactly what the `Nest` family of functions does in Mathematica. [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html), [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html), [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html), [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html). Would be neat if we had these built in to F#.

Comment: Please note that your ``for`` loop in the first example is iterated 11 times, not 10.

Answer (score 6):

Just trying to think outside the box here, but instead of folding over `randomIteration` with different arguments each time, you could create a chain of N `randomIteration` calls and call this chain once:

```
let repeat n =
    Seq.init n (fun _ u -> randomIteration u pms distances)
    |> Seq.reduce (>>)

initialize cities pms
|> repeat 10
|> printfn "Result: %A"
```

Comment: I really like this one, although a better name for the function would be `repeat` rather than `iterate`, as the latter implies mutability.

Comment: @Jwosty You are the first in like 35 years of me doing software who connotes iteration with mutation.

Answer (score 5):

> I could also use recursion with a counter variable, but that as well seems ackward.

That would seem natural to me: allowing the result of one call to be passed to the next without mutable state. Something like:

```
let interateSelf func initial count =
  let rec inner intermediate n =
    if n = 1 then
      func intermediate
    else
      inner (func intermediate) (n - 1)
  inner initial count
```

Comment: Terse version (cribbed from [F# News](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/06/dragon-curve-in-17-lines-of-f.html)) `let rec nest n f x = if n=0 then x else nest (n-1) f (f x)`

Comment: To "natural" I would add "idiomatic"

Comment: should it not be   'let rec inner intermediate n =' ?

Comment: @PaulB yes it should

Answer (score 4):

One easy change to make that less awkward is to use a sequence expression rather than `Seq.init`.

```
let result = {1..10} 
             |> Seq.fold (fun uNext i -> randomIteration uNext pms distances) u
```

If you really want to keep the `Seq.init` you could replace the identify function with the build-in one like this:

```
let result = Seq.init 10 id
             |> Seq.fold (fun uNext i -> randomIteration uNext pms distances) u
```

An alternative would be to create a recursive function something like this:

```
let result = let rec loop x i =
               match i with
               | 0 -> x
               | i -> loop (randomIteration x pms) (i-1)
             loop u 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slight variation on Nikon-the-Third's answer.  One could create a more general function that repeatedly applies another function:

```
let repeat n fn = List.init n (fun _ -> fn) |> List.reduce (>>)
```

This could then be used to create a named function that repeats the first 10 times:

```
let getNext10Times = repeat 10 (fun u -> randomIteration u pms distances)
getNext10Times u
```

or it could be used anonymously:

```
u |> repeat 10 (fun u -> randomIteration u pms distances)
```